# how to edit this code to show multiple files (it currently works with 1 file)?

Tags: bash, shell

I have created a shell script in order to find 2 files. While it works with 1 it does not work with 2 or multiple. Any help?

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="abc"

if [ -f "${FILENAME}"* ]
then

echo "EXISTS"

else

echo "NOT EXISTS"

fi
```

Expected: `EXISTS`

Error:

```
./test.sh: line 5: [: abc1.sh: binary operator expected
NOT EXISTS
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is here:

```
if [ -f "${FILENAME}"* ]
```

`-f` option accepts a single file. If there are more files that start
with `$FILENAME` then `*` is expanded and more than one file is passed
to `-f`. It's also reported by `shellcheck`:

```
$ ~/.cabal/bin/shellcheck test.sh

In test.sh line 5:
if [ -f "${FILENAME}"* ]
        ^-- SC2144: -f doesn't work with globs. Use a for loop.
```

If you want to check if there is at least one file that starts with
`$FILENAME` without using external tools such as `find` you need use
for loop like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="abc"

for file in "${FILENAME}"*
do
  if [ -f "$file" ]
  then
      echo File exists
      exit 0
  fi
done

echo File does not exist.
exit 1
```

Comment: Thanks Arkadiusz that runs perfectly. Take care

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to check if there less then 2 files with same name `abc*`:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="abc"
COUNT_FILES=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$FILENAME*" -type f | wc -l)

if [[ $COUNT_FILES -lt 2 ]]
then

echo "NOT EXISTS"

else

echo "EXISTS"

fi
```

Comment: Not so good. First, it will look for files recursively unlike `filename*`. Second, `wc  -l` will not correctly work with filenames that contain a newline.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thanx for comment. I added option `-maxdepth 1` for none recursively search.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ls /path/to/your/files* 1> /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "files do exist"
else
    echo "files do not exist"
fi
```

This is what I was looking for. What I wanted was a function that looks for single OR multiple files, which the code above performed perfectly. Thanks for the previous answers, much help.